# Hadoop and 3d Rendering of images

Tags: 3d, rendering, hadoop

I have to make a project Distributed rendering of a 3d image. I can use standard algorithms. The aim is to learn hadoop and not image processing. So can any one suggest what language should I use c++ or java and some standard implementation of a 3d renderer. Any other help would be highly useful ..

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop uses [Map/Reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_Reduce) functions for its data processing.  The data gets split up into manageable chunks for processing (Map phase), then recombined to give the result (Reduce phase).

There are specific languages for data processing (see [Pig](http://hadoop.apache.org/pig/) and [Hive](http://hadoop.apache.org/hive/)), or you can write your own M/R scripts using [Java, C++, python etc](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#A4).

I don't know anything about image processing, but if you're going to use Hadoop your first task will be to figure out how you can break your problem down into chunks which can be passed to the M/R process.  [Michael Noll's Map/Reduce tutorial](http://www.michael-noll.com/wiki/Writing_An_Hadoop_MapReduce_Program_In_Python) may help you get started.

HTH