# Using Apache Hadoop for rendering 3D images

Tags: java, 3d, hadoop, rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hadoop and 3d Rendering of images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696122/hadoop-and-3d-rendering-of-images)

It is possible to use Apache Hadoop (MapReduce) for rendering 3D images?

Comment: Java has support for threads which means you can use parallel processing. I'm not sure if JVM has to be setup to use more processors/cores if available or if this is handled by JVM by default (or by the OS).

Comment: This paper is about the same topic: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6106549

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason Hadoop couldn't be used.

If you are to use both the "map" *and* "reduce" phases of Hadoop, that implies splitting each *frame* across Hadoop nodes.

There's little to be gained from using Hadoop if you were to just use each node to render separate frames, although the abstract of the paper mentioned in the comments above suggests that HDFS works well for access to scene data and rendered frames.

I've written a stochastic ray tracer in Java which is currently multithreaded.  In this code I collect very large numbers of samples for each pixel, so in Hadoop the collection of those samples to produce the eventual pixel output would correspond well to Hadoop's "reduce" phase.

Comment: Thanks for answer. `both the "map" and "reduce" phases of Hadoop, that implies splitting each frame`
Hmm. Why both? I think on Map step I need to split one big frame into multiple "mini-frames", then put each mini-frame into Hadoop node. And on Reduce step I need to get results from nodes, and combine processed mini-frames into ONE, BIG frame. This is right? And which size must have a frame? Hundred GigaBytes per frame? And each frame must have definition measured in Gigapixels? (I think theres no reason to use Hadoop at smaller sizes of frames).

Comment: And what about splitting whole frames between Hadoop nodes?  Each frame will process a big frame, and on finish I get several frames and combine this frames into one "mini-movie"?

Comment: @MyTitle the reduce phase is also supposed to be able to be parallelised - that's unlikely to be useful when needing to take a (linear) sequence of frames to encode them into a video.   For individual frames, you could split them by pixel row, or (e.g.) 64x64 blocks, anything you want depending on your rendering model.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not, as long as your app don't require a short response time (something like less than a minute). I.e. it'll most likely be useless for 3D games, but if you are making a movie and have to process a lot of footage or something, it may make sense.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible - as most geometry tasks can be executed in parallel  fashion ( you have vertices and triangles and perform computations on them   based on projection matrix ) and in pipeline manner as invisible primitives will be just dropped from further computing